# How to perform and display the progress of a sequence of operations in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to invoke a sequence of operations and show live progress of the invocations and results of already executed operation on single page in PHP. The operation could be a commandline invocation or a DB update. The contents needs to refresh after executing each command. What is the best way to do this in PHP. Is there some library I could leverage?

EDIT: 
Here, I am not actually looking for terminal emulator. I need to perform a sequence of operations. An operation could be anything (a function call that returns a result). I need to show the result. I was wondering if there is a framework to do this. If not, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I am not actually looking for terminal emulator. I need to perform operations. An operation could be anything (a function call that returns a result).

Comment: it won't be an _emulator_ - but principles of interactive update are shown well there

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one of two ways:

1. (Recommended) Generate the main page with PHP (fast), and then perform the logic that requires time to complete using AJAX calls. If you use AJAX calls, you have many options on how to create progress status, such as with http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/ (google JavaScript progress bar for more.
2. Flush the buffer to force messages (which can include progress messages, JavaScript Progress Widget, etc) to update to the browser before the PHP page has fully loaded. According to the API page here, https://www.php.net/flush, this may or may not work well, depending on your web browser.

geremy

Comment: I was going to recommend a socket server using socket.io: http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `exec()` and `system()`:

http://php.net/function.exec
http://php.net/function.system

Those will give you basic functionality, but I'm not sure they will do the trick if the commands you are running have animated progress bars or require user input after they have been started.

Check out the other functions listed with those two as well, you may find a better fit for you.

Good luck!

Comment: How could this help with interactive status update?

Comment: PHP doesn't do interactive very well. Are you looking for a browser based implementation of command line functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Look into websockets. I implemented something similar using Ratchet (socketo.me) with WAMP ( web application message protocol ) and zmq. Any process could send a message via zmq to the websocket server and then to the client.